# Which security protocols are the todays state of the art in WSN?

Tags: iot

WSN (Wireless sensor networks) are mostly distributed low-power computers with sensing tasks that rely on limited battery life and therefore are not able to implement full-size security protocols. Depending on the kind of network (heterogeneous, homogeneous) and the environment they will be used in (likeliness of some attack scenarios) the security means used may depend a lot.

The question relates mostly to networks with homogeneous networks without internet connection that rely on some coarse distributed base stations or heterogeneous networks with only slightly differing nodes (towards computational power) that allow clusters to some extent.

Does anyone have an idea what today's state of the art protocols are for the different kinds of possible attacks? Key distribution methods, Intrusion detection systems, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One area is certainly low power WAN networks, with NB-IoT (CAT-M1 and CAT-NB), LoRa and Sigfox as most common examples. I cannot comment on security levels, but I NB-IoT (part of 4G) should be pretty OK.